# Accessing product attributes from within a class definition inside view.phtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm adding a small function to the code for our view.phtml to check if the product in question has certain atributes and then build a list from them.

At the top of my file I have

```
 <?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');?>
 <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

and elsewhere in my code I quite happily and without issue make use of such calls as:

```
<?php $_product->getColor();?>
```

All fine and dandy so far.

Later I declare a class AttributeList and within it's constructor I try to access values of $_product

```
 class AttributeList{  // AttributeList CLASS DEFINITION
   public $attributes = array();    
   public $count;
   function __construct(){ //CONSTRUCTOR FOR AttributeList CLASS
        $this->itemCount = 0;
        if($_product->getColor()){
        //DO SOME THINGS
        }
     }//CONSTRUCTOR ENDS    
   }// AttributeList CLASS ENDS
```

This causes my page not to load. If i change the conditions of the if statement to something arbitraraly true like "0 < 1" the code executes perfectly, so I presume the issue is that $_product is not visible from within my class definition.

Can someone explain why this is the case, and how i'm supposed to access the properties of my product from within my class definition?

Which stupidly obvious facet of magento or php am I overlooking here?

Comment: How did you declare your class? Have you created a module and extended the product view controller or?

Comment: It's defined directly inside my view.phtml, it only defines very simple objects which are only ever used within the context of my product pages, so it doesn't seem worth creating a module or helper class to let me use them globally. It's probably a quick and dirty way to do it, but it's worked fine for me before - I can comfortably declare a class, invoke new instances of it and access their values this way without issue.

Comment: That's really nasty solution! I suggest you to create a module for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very bad practice to put a class inside a view but to answer your question, use `Mage::registry('current_product')` inside your class:

```
<?php
class AttributeList {

    public $attributes = array();    
    public $count;
    public $product;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->itemCount = 0;
        $this->product = Mage::registry('current_product');

        if($this->_product->getColor()){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this.
Can you eleborate on why it's such bad practice? I'm fairly new to magento and it seemed like the most straight forward way to go about it.

Comment: Sure, search for MVC. A `.phtml` file in Magento is a view file which should contain only view information. You're now putting functionality into it by manipulating data, that should be handled in a helper, block or model dependent on what you exactly want.